# Excuting invalid password line even if the match in database

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

In the below code i am entering the correct username and password, but what is happening the its collecting the values from the form and when he reach to line 28 (if (password_verify($password, $row['cpass'])) {) its jumping to line 33 ($password_error = "Invalid password.";) even if the values entered is matching what in the database

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconn.php'; // assume this file sets up $conn PDO object

$username = "";
$password = "";
$username_error = "";
$password_error = "";
$login_error = "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);

  // Check clients table
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE cuid = :username');
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

  if ($count == 1) {
    // Check password
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT cpass FROM clients WHERE cuid = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if (password_verify($password, $row['cpass'])) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      header('Location: dashboard.html');
      exit;
    } else {
      $password_error = "Invalid password.";
    }
  } 

  // If the "Remember Me" checkbox is checked
  if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    setcookie('username', $username, time() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)); // 30 days expiration
    setcookie('password', $password, time() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)); // 30 days expiration
  }
}
?>
```

Is there any explanation for what is happening, I tried to delete the table in the database and re-create it and then enter the data, but the problem was not resolvedز

Comment: What value do you have stored in your database exactly??

Comment: please also show the code of the insert#

Comment: To be clear, the password in your database is hashed using one of PHP native hashing functions, right?

Comment: Is `filter_input` *modifying* the input in any way?  For passwords one can expect it to contain "special characters" for example.  If that function changes the value at all then it's no longer the correct password.

Comment: Don't put passwords in cookies! Use native PHP sessions.

Comment: the values in the table are -> password is: simo@2010 and username is: jimmy

Comment: @AlexHowansky thanks to mention that, i will work on it

Comment: Don't put the plain text password in the database, it should be the hash you get back from calling password_hash(). Make sure the field is long enough to hold it, they're pretty long strings.

Comment: @AlexHowansky the data type i am using it for the password column is: text. And regarding the password format, is it a good idea to force users to type it in specific way. i mean I would like to give user to choose their own password.

Comment: They absolutely can choose their own password, but you should never store it as plain text. You pass what they type to password_hash(), that gives you back a long string, and that's what you store in the database. Then you use password_verify() to compare the password from the form to the hashed value from the database. See [here](https://phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) for an example.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I got your idea, it's much clearer to me now and i will add it in registration form. But i would solve this code cuz really i give up with it.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't apply the `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` on the password as that will rewrite certain characters (e.g. `<` will be replaced with `&lt;`). Just retrieve the raw submitted password with `$password = $_POST['password']`

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did as you mention by changing to below code but the issue still exist:   $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  $password = $_POST['password'];